# Is there a Go function that works like linux cut?

Tags: string, go, split, cut

This is probably a very basic question, but I have not been able to find an answer after reviewing the strings package docs.

Basically, all I want to do is the equivalent of:

`echo "hello world" | cut -d" " -f2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "hello world" | cut -d" " -f2
```

This splits the string `"hello world"` using spaces as delimeters, and selects only the 2nd part (1-indexed).

In Go for spitting there is [`strings.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) which returns a slice, which you can index or slice however you like.

```
s := "hello world"

fmt.Println(strings.Split(s, " ")[1])
```

This outputs the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JoQPiW0m0f6). If the input is not guaranteed to have 2 parts, the above indexing (`[1]`) might panic. Check the length of the slice before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`strings.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) function which splits the string at the specified sub-string.

There are also the functions [`Fields(s string) []string`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields), and [`FieldsFunc(s string, f func(rune) bool) []string`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#FieldsFunc).

The former split the string at spaces, and the later uses the given function to determine if the string must be split.

The difference between `Split` and `Fields` is that `Fields` consider multiple consecutive spaces as one split location. `strings.Fields("  foo bar  baz   "))` yields `["foo" "bar" "baz"]`, and `strings.Split("  foo bar  baz   ", " ")` yields `["" "" "foo" "bar" "" "baz" "" "" ""]`.